# como ir buscar valores de tabela em C#

Tags: c#, sql

eu tenho este seguinte código, como é que faço para me devolver o que está no campo utilizador da tabela utilizador ?

```
 public int GetPerfilId(string username)
 {
     int result = 0;

     if(db != null)
     {
         DAL.Utilizador uti = db.Utilizador.Where(u => u.username == username).FirstOrDefault();


         if (uti != null)
         {
             DAL.Utilizador_Perfil utip = db.Utilizador_Perfil.Where(up => up.idutilizador == uti.id).FirstOrDefault();

             if (utip != null) result = utip.idperfil;
         }

         //DAL.Utilizador_Perfil utip = db.Utilizador_Perfil.Where(x => x.Utilizador.username == username).FirstOrDefault();
         //if (utip != null) result = utip.idperfil;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tiago, essa pergunta está muito vaga, poderia colocar mais detalhes? aproveitando, faça um [tour] e vaja como o StacOverFlow funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo simples que posso te dar é o seguinte: Digamos que eu tenha que buscar todos os dados dos clientes (que não se repetem) do meu banco de dados.

```
// String de BUSCA SQL (No seu caso será o de UTILIZADOR)
private string SQL_CLIENTES = "SELECT DISTINCT *" +
    " FROM cliente";

// Abrindo/Recuperando uma conexão com NPGSQL (Caso não esteja instalado é necessário ir em TOOLS-> NUGET PACKAGE MANAGER -> MANAGE NUGET PACKAGE FOR SOLUTION -> PESQUISAR NPGSQL e INSTALAR NO SEU PROJETO.

    private static NpgsqlConnection conn = null;

    public static NpgsqlConnection getConexao()
    {
      if (conn == null)
      {
        string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};", "SEU_SERVIDOR_POSTGRESQL", "5432", "SEU_USUARIO_POSTGRESQL", "SUA_SENHA_POSTGRESQL", "SEU_ESQUEMA_POSTGRESQL");
        conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
      }
      return conn;
    }

    NpgsqlConnection conexao = ConexaoDAO.getConexao();
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(SQL_CLIENTES, conexao);
    NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    // Aqui eu coloquei uma lista de clientes (NO SEU CASO É UTILIZADOR)
    private List<Cliente> listaClientes = new List<Cliente>();

    // PERCORRENDO TODOS OS RESULTADOS ENCONTRADOS NA TABELA
    while (reader.Read())
    {
      // INSERINDO NO OBJETO CLIENTE OS ATRIBUTOS DO CLIENTE (NO SEU CASO É UTILIZADOR)
      Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
      cliente.Nome1 = Convert.ToString(reader["nome_cli"]);
      cliente.CidadeUF1 = Convert.ToString(reader["cidade_uf"]);
      // INSERINDO NA LISTA DE CLIENTES
      listaClientes.Add(cliente);
    }
    // FECHANDO O READER
    reader.Close();

   //OBS: ASSIM, SEUS UTILIZADORS (NO MEU CASO CLIENTE) ESTARÃO NA LISTA DE CLIENTES, DAÍ É SÓ MANIPULAR DO JEITO QUE VOCÊ NECESSITA
```

Comment: primeiro, não se deve colocar dados sensiveis no codigo, você deveria colocar ela no app/web.config... leia mais em [Best practices for deploying passwords and other sensitive data to ASP.NET and Azure App Service](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure)

Comment: O AP em nenhum momento mencionou que está utilizando ADO.NET ou PosgreSQL.

Comment: Por fim, criar um método que cria uma conexao, abre a mesma e entrega ela já aberta, é pedir para que uma conexões fiquem abertas, ao invés disto, utilize o bloco `using` para todos os objetos que implementam `IDisposable`... `NpgsqlConnection`, `NpgsqlCommand` e `NpgsqlDataReader`.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta e peço desculpa a todos pela não clareza da minha pergunta